# c# propertyGrid key listener

Tags: c#, propertygrid, keylistener

I have a propertyGrid;
PropertyGrid contains lots of properties storing number values;
What I want to do is to enter one of those properties and instead of writing new number in it, by pressing arrows UP/DOWN increase/decrease its value.

Any ideas on how to handle that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your UI Type Editor.
Look at this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx) just to know where to start and to get a valuable example.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a PropertyGrid and I used this library about 1 year ago :
http://wpg.codeplex.com/

I don't remember if it was doing what you want but it was VERY complete !
I do remember that on int (for example) you had some  and  buttons

Comment: Thanks for reply, though your suggestion is in WPF and I am not using it in my project. 
Taking your suggestion would cause me to make major changes in code and I would like to figure how to make it without using WPF...